# iOS Loss of image quality and resolution

Tags: xcode, uiimage, resolution

I have and imageview that i use throughout my app. It can hold a picture from the gallery or from the camera.

In the end I upload it to a webserver using php.

But where does xcode downscale my image? Ipad pictures are aprox. 300x300px. 
Tried downloading a 1000+ x 1000+ pixels image, but it looks like it gets downscaled once i open it trough uiimagepicker. In my gallery its fine before i start my app, but when i add it via my gallery its low res.

I need these images with the resolution they were made with.

Is there any way to obtatain that?

Comment: I figured it out myself. Damn, spendt all night trying to get this to work. 

I changed the line where it saves the image from:

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

to: 
<pre>  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; <code>

:)

Comment: Yes you're right, you need to use OriginalImage instead of EditedImage to get them with the resolution they were made with but the question is why it gets downscaled when using EditedImage? I face this problem and I can't get any solution for it and I need to use EditedImage in my case. Any idea?

Comment: Sawsan: I believe you need to get the UIImagePickerControllerCropRect and then create a proper "EditedImage" based on it