# Issue with UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage: Reducing the quality of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app I give the ability to the user to edit the photos before uploading them. My question is why do we get the photos with low quality when using `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` ?

I searched for this issue and I didn't find the answer [check here this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904940/issue-with-uiimagepickercontrollereditedimage) and I'm sure the photo is high quality and I didn't crop or zoom it as explained in that link.

When I use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` , I get the photos with the quality they were made with.

Here is my code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *pickedImage;

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage)
        pickedImage = editedImage;
    else
        pickedImage = originalImage;

    if (Picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera ) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, self, nil, nil);
    }

    pickedImage = [pickedImage fixOrientation];

    .
    //Additional steps 
    .
    .
}
```

Any idea?

Another question ensures that there is an issue with EditedImage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872667/ios-loss-of-image-quality-and-resolution)

Comment: When you are done taking the picture do you see the editing screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904940/issue-with-uiimagepickercontrollereditedimage)

Comment: @hasseg no dear, it did not solve the problem for me. As you can see in my question, I already posted the same link that you added in your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: @SawsanAlKhdair The question you're asking is the same, though, right? That `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` is of lowered quality, and what to do about it?

Comment: @hasseg yes but the answer did not solve my problem